# Postprocessing Elastic results with another search (migrating from Solr)

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, elasticsearch-painless

I'm currently migrating an application from Solr to Elastic and stumbled over an interesting Solr feature that I cannot reproduce in Elastic: The query to Solr returns a postprocessing flag that does a quality check on the result, indicating wether all tokens are found in the result field.

```
q  = some_field:(the brown fox)
fl = some_field, full_match:exists(query({!edismax v='some_field:(the brown fox)' mm='100%'}))
```

The Solr result looks as follows:

```
{
    "response": {
        "docs": [
            {
                "some_field": "The Brown Bear",
                "full_match": false
            },
            {
                "some_field": "The Quick Brown Fox",
                "full_match": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The flag is used by the client to further process the result documents, independent of the score (which I omitted in the example). I found this quite smart, as the tokenization and distributed computation power of Solr is used instead of doing everything in the client.

Now in Elastic I assume this should be done the `script_fields` block, but actually I have no clue how to perform a subquery with a painless script and after two days of investigation I doubt that this is possible at all:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "some_field": "the brown fox"
        }
    },
    "_source": [
        "some_field"
    ],
    "script_fields": {
        "full_match": {
            "script": "???" <-- Search with Painless script?
        }
    }
}
```

Any creative ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Elasticsearch's [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-queries-and-filters) in combination with the [minimum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) parameter and setting that to 100% to match only documents where all tokens match?

You would then be able to detect queries where all tokens match in the response. You can also set "boost": 0 to avoid affecting the score of your main query.

Here's an example request:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "message": {
                            "query": "the brown fox",
                            "_name": "main_query"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "message": {
                            "query": "the brown fox",
                            "_name": "all_tokens_match",
                            "minimum_should_match": "100%",
                            "boost": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You would then get a response that looks a bit like this:

```
{
    "hits": [
        {
            "_score": 0.99938476,
            "_source": {
                "message": "The Quick Brown Fox"
            },
            "matched_queries": [
                "main_query",
                "all_tokens_match"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_score": 0.38727614,
            "_source": {
                "message": "The Brown Bear"
            },
            "matched_queries": [
                "main_query"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Documents that all tokens in your query match will then have **all_tokens_match** included in the **matched_queries** part of the response.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Unlike Solr, the flag is now calculated in the search phase, and not in the fetch phase. But this seems to be no big performance issue.